# HTML wont pass argument to flask missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: html, flask

I can't figure this error out, I am passing the `chirp_id` from this `<a href>`
the error `TypeError: createCmt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chirp_id'`

The Snippet of the code

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    {% if chirp %}

    <h2>{{ chirp[1] }}</h2>
    <p>
        By : {{ chirp[2] }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ chirp[3] }}
    </p>
       
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url_for('createCmt', chirp_id='{{ chirp[0] }}') }}"> + Comment </a>
    </div>

    {% else %}
    <h3>
        Invalid comment
    </h3>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The URL that is called by the button is this

```html
@app.route('/comment/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createCmt(chirp_id):
    # check if user is logged in
    if not session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json() or {}
        if data.get('body'):
            user_id = session.get('user_id')
            body = data.get('body', '')            

            body = body.strip()
            sql_params = (chirp_id, user_id, body)

            conn = db_connection()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            sql = """
                INSERT INTO commentary (chirp_id, user_id, body) VALUES (%d, %d, '%s')
            """ % sql_params
            cur.execute(sql)
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
            return jsonify({'status': 200, 'message': 'Success', 'redirect': '/'})

        return jsonify({'status': 500, 'message': 'No Data submitted'})

    return render_template('comment/create.html')
```

Does this mean that the `chirp_id` isn't being passed from the `chirp_id='{{ chirp[0] }}'`
in the HTML? or I am just stupid

**EDIT**

this is my create.html that extends to the first HTML

```html
{% extends "comment/form.html" %}

{% block title %}
Create a Comment
{% endblock %}

{% block button %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="offset-2 col-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="btnCreate" id="btnCreate" onclick="createCUM()">Create</button>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and the javascript for getting the body value

```js
function createCUM(chirp_id) {
    var body = document.getElementById("body").value;

    axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/comment/create/" + chirp_id,
        data: {
            body: body,
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    }).then(
        (response) => {
            var data = response.data;
            if (data.redirect) {
                // redirect exists, then set the URL to the redirect
                window.location.href = data.redirect;
            }

            if (data.status == 500) {
                alert(data.error);
                window.location.href = "/";  // redirect to home page
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Comment: Instead of chirp_id='{{ chirp[0] }}' do '{}'.format(chirp[0])

Comment: @WinmariManzano do you mean like this 
        href="{{ url_for('createCmt', chirp_id='{}'.format(chirp[0])) }}"

i am a lil bit confused, sorry

Comment: Now that the argument is fixed. What kind of link do you want to achieve? If chip[0] = 5, then would you like "/comment/create/5"?

Comment: @WinmariManzano yes, after it and  iclick create the comment it will redirect me to index and the new comment will be inserted to the database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your @app.route seems to be lacking a paramater, would you like to do it as

```py
@app.route("/comment/create/<chirp_id>", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
```

2. Try to change your href to

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url_for('createCmt', chirp_id='{}'.format(chirp[0])) }}"> + Comment </a>
```

**additional edit**

I tried to run it I did this

Route for the a href

```py
@app.route("/test")
def testing():
  return render_template("testerer.html", chirp_id = 123)
```

Route for the post

```py
@app.route("/comment/create/<chirp_id>", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def createCmt(chirp_id):
  return f"{chirp_id}"
```

HTML

```html
  <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url_for('createCmt', chirp_id='{}'.format(chirp_id) ) }}"> + Comment </a>
```

Comment: Let me know if this would fix it~

Comment: it fix the argument problem, and on the terminal it said ""POST /comment/create HTTP/1.1" 404 -"

Comment: Hello, have you fixed it? If not then check my example above.

Comment: yes thankyou , its fixed the  argument to flask missing 1 required positional argument error, and but when I try to post a comment, it said "POST /comment/create HTTP/1.1" 404 -"

Comment: Have you tried to look if your + Comment is giving you a valid link? Like /comment/create/1234 or just /comment/create?

Comment: well after some modifies in the javascript to make the URL the same as in phyton, it said "Exception on /comment/create/undefined [POST]"

Comment: Now it seems to be a problem with the variable (chirp[0]) itself passing out invalid values

Comment: well, i try to run the sql on the postgressql, it seems fine to me, but on when I press comment, it redirects me to /comment/create/2

I have another HTML for the header and js for creating the comment, would you like to see it?